# Align <input> & <button> tags

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout

I have an ordered list which has a `<input type="text"...` and `<button>` field. When I render them I get the fields in 2 separate lines. How do I get them to come in the same line?

HTML-

```
<li>
    <input type="text" value="Paste URL here"></input>
    <button id="i">Go</button>
</li>
```

I have even removed them from `<li>` & put them in a separate `<div>` with no success. What CSS needs to be added here to overcome this default behavior?

**UPDATE:** I have now removed these 2 tags from the ordered list & put them in a `<div>`. It looks like this now -

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <input id="url" type="text" value="Paste URL here"></input>
    <button id="i" style="font-size:10px; margin:2px;">Go</button>
</div>
```

No effect on trying `float:left;` or `display:inline-block`.

Comment: what browser? i tried on Firefox & IE8, they line up at same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" style="float: left; width: 200px;" id="url" value="Paste URL here">
    <button style="font-size: 10px; margin: 2px; float: left;" id="i">Go</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit button seem to have different default margin and padding values in different browsers.

I assume this must be in [some reset Stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet) as this is not the only annoying cross browser "default" values discrepancy. When is the web going to standardize this is another subject.

This is how we do it:

```
#searchForm {
    position: relative;   // you must keep this
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
input#searchEntry {
    padding: 0;    // you must keep this
    margin: 0;     // you must keep this
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 198px;
    font: 17px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
input#searchBtn{
    padding: 0;   // you must keep this
    margin: 0;    // you must keep this
    position: absolute;   // you must keep this
    left: 203px;
    top: 2px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 42px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url(http://yourDomain/img/yourPrettySearchIcon.png) buttonface no-repeat 9px 1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:hand;
}


<form id="searchForm" name="mySearchForm" action="myPage.html" method="post">
    <input name="searchEntry" value="" id="searchEntry" type="text"/>
    <input name="searchBtn" value="" id="searchBtn" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I noticed very small discrepancies between IE8, Firefox and GChrome but there may be in other browsers.

The form here has its position set to "relative" so that when I set the button's position to absolute, the button position itself relatively to the searchForm.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the same line.

Please check the width of `<li> and <li>`'s parent tag (`<ul>` or something).
I think that can cause this.

Comment: I have not set any width to `<li>` or `<ul>`. Also now I have moved those elements out of `<li>`. Still no use.

Comment: you might have to set it then.

Comment: Then you may try with table style:<table>
    <tr width="100%">
  <td width="80%"><input id="url" type="text" value="Paste URL here"/></td>
  <td width="20%"><button id="i" style="font-size:10px; margin:2px;" value="Go"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>

Comment: @Movie Yoda: and one more thing that remove the style for button.